# How can I convert these VB calculations to Objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, vb.net, xcode, math

I have an older program that I wrote some time ago in VB then late updated for VB.Net. The program calculates the ephemerides of comets based on orbital elements downloaded from the Minor Planet Center website. I am now trying to make an iPhone/iPad application using the same idea and the same calculations. Unfortunately I am too new at objective-c that trying to convert the extensive calculations is proving quite difficult for me. I am hoping that someone can help me out and at least give me some pointers.

In particular, I have no idea how to accomplish this in objective-c:

```
    Dim d1 As Date = DateSerial(yr_peri%, mo_peri%, dy_peri%)
    dateser# = d1.ToOADate()
    dateser# = dateser# + frac_day_peri#
    jdperi# = 2415018.5 + dateser#
```

and this:

```vb
    ' Find Julian Day Number of start date & time
    Dim d2 As Date = DateSerial(yr%, mo%, dd%)
    Dim inputdate# = d2.ToOADate()
    jdp# = inputdate + 2415018.5 ' use this day for phenom (rise/set) calcs
    jd# = jdp# + fd# ' add fractional days
```

Here is the full VB version of the calculations in case it helps to understand the context:

```vb
Public Sub calc(ByVal cname$, ByVal qq#, ByVal e#, ByVal w#, ByVal om#, ByVal I#, ByVal yr_peri%, ByVal mo_peri%, ByVal day_peri#, ByVal abs_mag#, ByVal mag_n#)
    Dim ep#
    Dim dy_peri%, frac_day_peri#, dateser#, jdperi#
    Dim yr%, mo%, dd%, fd#
    Dim jdp#, jd#, interval#
    Dim twi%, p_date#, ut#, er%
    Dim t#, tt#, f#, p#, g#, q#, h#, r#
    Dim a1#, a2#, b1#, b2#, c1#, c2#
    Dim sdt#, a#, n#, period#, m#, e0#
    Dim mrs#, frs%, ers0#, drs#, jrs%, mrs1#, e2#
    Dim tv#, v#, r1#, r2#, w0#, s#, s0#
    Dim x#, y#, z#, ls#, ms#, es#, th#, vs#, c#, th2000#
    Dim rs#, xs#, ys#, zs#, xx#, yy#, radeg#, rad#, ra#, ras$
    Dim dl#, dlm#, sd#, dec#, ds$
    Dim cospsi#, psi#, elong#, cosbeta#, beta#, phase#
    Dim ha#, ang#, az#, sinalt#, alt#, m1#, vl#
    Dim Lati$, Longi$
    Dim outpt$

    '----------------------------------------------
    '** AA=ASTRONOMICAL ALGORITHMS BY JEAN MEEUS **
    '----------------------------------------------
    counter% = 0
    ep# = 23.439291  ' year 2000, AA page 214

    cname$ = Trim(cname$)

    'Get orbital elements
    MainForm.grpEphemerides.Text = "Comet: " & cname$ & " - " + when$ ' Name
    'qq# = Val(comet$(ind%, 1))       ' perihelion dist
    'e# = Val(comet$(ind%, 2))        ' eccentricity (1=parabola)
    'w# = Val(comet$(ind%, 3))        ' arg of perihelion - little omega
    'om# = Val(comet$(ind%, 4))       ' long of ascending node - big omega
    'I# = Val(comet$(ind%, 5))        ' inclination
    'yr_peri% = Val(comet$(ind%, 6))  ' year
    'mo_peri% = Val(comet$(ind%, 7))  ' month
    'day_peri# = Val(comet$(ind%, 8)) ' day
    'abs_mag# = Val(comet$(ind%, 9))  ' magnitude coef #1
    'mag_n# = Val(comet$(ind%, 10))   ' magnitude coef #2

    ' Find JD of perihelion
    dy_peri% = Int(day_peri#) ' day
    frac_day_peri# = day_peri# - dy_peri% ' fractional day
    Dim d1 As Date = DateSerial(yr_peri%, mo_peri%, dy_peri%)
    dateser# = d1.ToOADate()
    dateser# = dateser# + frac_day_peri#
    jdperi# = 2415018.5 + dateser#

    ' Start date/time
    yr% = Val(MainForm.txtYear.Text)
    mo% = Val(MainForm.txtMonth.Text)
    dd% = Val(MainForm.txtDay.Text)
    fd# = Val(MainForm.txtHour.Text) / 24 + Val(MainForm.txtMin.Text) / 1440 + Val(MainForm.txtSec.Text) / 86400
    lat# = Val(MainForm.txtLat.Text)
    lon# = Val(MainForm.txtLon.Text)

    ' Find Julian Day Number of start date & time
    Dim d2 As Date = DateSerial(yr%, mo%, dd%)
    Dim inputdate# = d2.ToOADate()
    jdp# = inputdate + 2415018.5 ' use this day for phenom (rise/set) calcs
    jd# = jdp# + fd# ' add fractional days

    interval# = Val(MainForm.txtInterval.Text)


    ' Determine if fixed times or rise/set phenomena
    If MainForm.rdbFixedTimes.Checked = True Then
        twi% = 0 ' use fixed times
    Else
        twi% = 1 ' use twilight times
        interval# = Int(interval#) ' Set integer days (fraction doesn't make sense)
        If interval# < 1 Then interval# = 1 ' make sure interval is at least one day
    End If

    '-----------
    ' Loop here
    '-----------
    While counter% <= Val(MainForm.txtNumSteps.Text)

        If twi% = 1 Then
            'Serial date of this calculation
            p_date# = jdp# - 2415018.5
            Call phenom(p_date#, ut#, er%) ' calcs for rise/set, returns er% (among other stuff)
            jd# = Int(p_date#) + 2415018.5 + ut# / 24 + 1 / 2880

            If er% = 1 Then ' er%=1 means no phenom (ex: sunrise) that day
                ser_date# = jd# - 2415018.5
                outpt$ = Format$(ser_date#, "mm/dd/yy") + "           " + "No Rise/Set Phenomena on this Date"
                GoTo No_phenom
            End If

        End If

        ' Days from perihelion of comet
        t# = jd# - jdperi#

        ' Time (in Julian Centuries (36525 days)) since 1900 Jan 0.5 ET
        ' AA page 151

        tt# = (jd# - 2451545.0#) / 36525.0!

        '--------------  CALC F,G,H,P,Q,R (PP214 IN AA)  ---------------
        f# = Cos(dr# * om#)
        p# = -Sin(dr# * om#) * Cos(dr# * I#)
        g# = Sin(dr# * om#) * Cos(dr# * ep#)
        q# = Cos(dr# * om#) * Cos(dr# * I#) * Cos(dr# * ep#) - Sin(dr# * I#) * Sin(dr# * ep#)
        h# = Sin(dr# * om#) * Sin(dr# * ep#)
        r# = Cos(dr# * om#) * Cos(dr# * I#) * Sin(dr# * ep#) + Sin(dr# * I#) * Cos(dr# * ep#)

        '----------------  CALC A1,A2,B1,B2,C1,C2 (PP214 AA)  -----------------
        Call rec2pol(p#, f#, a1#, a2#)
        Call rec2pol(q#, g#, b1#, b2#)
        Call rec2pol(r#, h#, c1#, c2#)

        '---------------  SIDEREAL TIME AT GREENWICH (PP84 AA) ----------------
        ' In degrees
        sdt# = 280.46061837 + 360.98564736629 * (jd# - 2451545) + 0.000387933 * tt# * tt# - tt# * tt# * tt# / 38710000
        sdt# = sdt# - 360 * Int(sdt# / 360)
        '-------------------  CALC ECCENTRIC & TRUE ANOMALY  --------------------
        If e# < 1 Then ' elliptical motion (pp214 AA)
            a# = qq# / (1 - e#) ' semi major axis (AU)
            n# = 0.9856076686 / a# / Sqrt(a#) ' mean motion (deg/day)
            period# = 360 / n# / 365.25
            MainForm.lblOrbitInf.Text = "Semimajor axis: " + Format$(a#, "#.000") + " AU    Period: " + Format$(period#, "#.00") + " Years"
            m# = n# * t# ' mean anomaly
            e0# = rd# * e# ' "modified" eccentricity, page 187)

            'ecc anomaly (page 195)
            mrs# = m# * dr#
            frs% = Sign(mrs#)
            mrs# = Abs(mrs#) / (2 * pi#)
            mrs# = (mrs# - Int(mrs#)) * 2 * pi# * frs%
            If mrs# < 0 Then mrs# = mrs# + 2 * pi#
            frs% = 1
            If mrs# > pi# Then frs% = -1
            If mrs# > pi# Then mrs# = 2 * pi# - mrs#
            ers0# = pi# / 2
            drs# = pi# / 4
            For jrs% = 1 To 53
                mrs1# = ers0# - e# * Sin(ers0#)
                ers0# = ers0# + drs# * Sign(mrs# - mrs1#)
                drs# = drs# / 2
            Next jrs%
            ers0# = ers0# * frs%
            e2# = ers0# * rd#

            'alpha# = (1 - e#) / (4 * e# + .5)
            'beta# = m# / (8 * e# + 1)
            'signbeta% = Sgn(beta#)
            'cube# = beta# + signbeta% * Sqr(beta# ^ 2 + alpha# ^ 3)
            'signz% = Sgn(cube#)
            'zz# = signz% * (Abs(cube#)) ^ (1 / 3)
            'ss0# = zz# - alpha# / 2
            'ss# = ss0# - .078 * ss0# ^ 5 / (1 + e#)
            'e1# = m# + e# * (3 * ss# - 4 * ss# ^ 3)

            'loop1% = 0 ' counter
1040:
            'e2# = e1# + (m# + e0# * Sin(dr# * e1#) - e1#) / (1 - e# * Cos(dr# * e1#))

            'If Abs(e2# - e1#) < .0000000001 Or loop1% > 1000 Then  ' e2#:ecc anom found
            tv# = Sqrt((1 + e#) / (1 - e#)) * Tan(dr# * e2# / 2)
            v# = 2 * rd# * Atan(tv#) ' true anomaly
            r1# = a# * (1 - e# * Cos(dr# * e2#)) ' dist from sun AU
            GoTo 2120
            'Else
            '    e1# = e2# ' new ecc anomaly
            '    loop1% = loop1% + 1
            '    GoTo 1040
            'End If

        Else ' parabolic motion (pp225 AA)
            MainForm.lblOrbitInf.Text = "This comet has a parabolic orbit-semimajor axis and period not determined"
            w0# = 0.0364911624 * t# / qq# / Sqrt(qq#)
            s# = 0
2110:
            s0# = (2 * s# * s# * s# + w0#) / 3 / (s# * s# + 1)

            If Abs(s# - s0#) > 0.0000000001 Then
                s# = s0#
                GoTo 2110
            End If

            s# = s0#
            v# = 2 * rd# * Atan(s#) ' true anomaly
            r1# = qq# * (1 + s# * s#) ' distance from sun (AU)
        End If

2120:
        v# = v# - 360 * Int(v# / 360) ' true anomaly
        'r1#= dist from sun in au (above)
        r2# = r1# * 92955807.0# ' Dist from sun (miles)

        '--------  CALC HELIOCENTRIC RECT COORD OF COMET (PP215 AA)  ----------
        x# = r1# * a2# * Sin(dr# * (a1# + w# + v#))
        y# = r1# * b2# * Sin(dr# * (b1# + w# + v#))
        z# = r1# * c2# * Sin(dr# * (c1# + w# + v#))

        '--------  CALC GEOCENTRIC RECT COORD OF SUN (PP151,152 AA)  ---------
        ls# = 280.46645 + 36000.76983 * tt# + 0.0003032 * tt# * tt#
        ls# = ls# - 360 * Int(ls# / 360)

        ms# = 357.5291 + 35999.0503 * tt# - 0.0001559 * tt# * tt# - 0.00000048 * tt# * tt# * tt#
        ms# = ms# - 360 * Int(ms# / 360)

        es# = 0.016708617 - 0.000042037 * tt# - 0.0000001236 * tt# * tt#

        c# = (1.9146 - 0.004817 * tt# - 0.000014 * tt# * tt#) * Sin(dr# * ms#) + (0.019993 - 0.000101 * tt#) * Sin(2 * dr# * ms#) + 0.00029 * Sin(3 * dr# * ms#)

        th# = ls# + c# ' TH is Sun's true longitude
        vs# = ms# + c# ' VS is Sun's true anomaly

        ' pp152 AA
        th2000# = th# - 0.01397 * (yr% + mo% / 12 + dd% / 365 - 2000) ' Sun true long referred to 2000

        ' sun's radius vector
        rs# = (1.000001018 * (1 - es# * es#)) / (1 + es# * Cos(dr# * vs#))

        ' rectangular coord of sun (pp159 AA)
        xs# = rs# * Cos(dr# * th2000#)                  ' Xsun
        ys# = rs# * Sin(dr# * th2000#) * Cos(dr# * ep#) ' Ysun
        zs# = rs# * Sin(dr# * th2000#) * Sin(dr# * ep#) ' Zsun

        '-------------  CALC GEOCENTRIC RA & DEC (PP 119 IN AFFC)  --------------
        xx# = xs# + x#
        yy# = ys# + y#
        Call rec2pol(xx#, yy#, radeg#, rad#)
        ra# = radeg# / 15 ' RA of comet (2000) in hours
        ' 0 means time
        ras$ = dec2ddmm(ra#, 0) ' ra in string form

        'dist from comet to earth (au)
        dl# = Sqrt((xs# + x#) ^ 2 + (ys# + y#) ^ 2 + (zs# + z#) ^ 2)
        dlm# = dl# * 92955807.0# ' distance from earth in miles

        sd# = (zs# + z#) / dl#

        'DEC of comet (2000)
        dec# = rd# * Atan(sd# / Sqrt(-sd# * sd# + 1))
        ' 1 means angle
        ds$ = dec2ddmm(dec#, 1) ' dec in string form

        ' Calc elongation
        cospsi# = (rs# * rs# + dl# * dl# - r1# * r1#) / (2 * rs# * dl#)
        psi# = -Atan(cospsi# / Sqrt(-cospsi# * cospsi# + 1)) + pi# / 2
        elong# = psi# * rd#
        elong# = elong# - 360 * Int(elong# / 360)

        ' Calc phase
        cosbeta# = (r1# * r1# + dl# * dl# - rs# * rs#) / (2 * r1# * dl#)
        beta# = -Atan(cosbeta# / Sqrt(-cosbeta# * cosbeta# + 1)) + pi# / 2
        phase# = beta# * rd#
        phase# = phase# - 360 * Int(phase# / 360)


        '------------  CALCULATE ALTITUDE & AZIMUTH (AA PP89)  --------------
        ha# = sdt# - lon# - radeg#
        yy# = Sin(dr# * ha#)
        xx# = (Cos(dr# * ha#) * Sin(dr# * lat#) - Tan(dr# * dec#) * Cos(dr# * lat#))
        ' rectangular to polar
        Call rec2pol(xx#, yy#, ang#, rad#)
        az# = ang# + 180
        az# = az# - 360 * Int(az# / 360)
        sinalt# = Sin(dr# * lat#) * Sin(dr# * dec#) + Cos(dr# * lat#) * Cos(dr# * dec#) * Cos(dr# * ha#)
        alt# = rd# * Atan(sinalt# / Sqrt(1 - sinalt# * sinalt#))

        '--------------  CALC EST MAGNITUDES & ORBITAL VELOCITY (AA PP 216)  ---------------
        m1# = abs_mag# + 5 * Log(dl#) / Log(10) + 2.5 * mag_n# * Log(r1#) / Log(10)

        If e# < 1 Then
            vl# = 42.1219 * Sqrt((1 / r1#) - (1 / (2 * a#))) ' elliptical orbital velocity, page 223
        Else
            vl# = 42.1219 * Sqrt(1 / r1#) ' parabolic orital velocity (my approximation)
        End If

        '-------------  Stuff for output form  -------------
        Dim dt As DateTime = DateTime.FromOADate(dateser#)
        MainForm.lblJDperi.Text = "Date of perihelion: " + dt.ToString("dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss") + " UTC  JD: " + Format$(jdperi#, "#.00000")
        Lati$ = "   "
        Longi$ = " "
        If lat# > 0 Then Lati$ = "N  " Else Lati$ = "S  "
        If lon# > 0 Then Longi$ = "W" Else Longi$ = "E"
        MainForm.lblLoc.Text = "Observing Location: " + Format$(lat#, "+00.0000;-00.0000") + Chr(176) + Lati$ + Format$(lon#, "+000.0000;-000.0000") + Chr(176) + Longi$

        'Serial date of this calculation
        ser_date# = jd# - 2415018.5

        ' put the main info into a string
        dt = DateTime.FromOADate(ser_date#)
        outpt = dt.ToString("MM/dd/yy   HH:mm:ss") & "   " & ras$ & "   " & ds$ & "  " & Format$(alt#, "+00.0;-00.0") & Chr(176) & "  " & Format$(az#, "000.0") & Chr(176)
        outpt = outpt & "   " & Format$(r1#, "00.0000") & "   " & Format$(dl#, "00.0000") & "  " & Format$(m1#, "+00.0;-00.0") + "   " & Format$(elong#, "000.0") & Chr(176)

No_phenom:

        ' put the string into the list box
        MainForm.lstPosition.Items.Add(outpt)

        ' put the "extra" data into the array
        extra#(counter%, 0) = t#     ' time to perih
        extra#(counter%, 1) = vl#    ' speed
        extra#(counter%, 2) = phase# ' phase
        extra#(counter%, 3) = v#     ' true anomaly

        ' Increment counter
        counter% = counter% + 1

        ' New JD
        jd# = jd# + interval# 
        jdp# = jdp# + interval#

    End While ' do again until done

End Sub
```

I appreciate any help or direction anyone can give on converting this function to objective-c.

Regards,
Keith

Comment: While I doubt anyone here will rewrite this in Objective-C for you looks like you will mostly be working with `NSDate` and and plenty of math functions http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cmath/

Comment: I am sorry, perhaps I gave the wrong impression. I am not looking for anyone to rewrite this for me. I am really struggling with those two `DateSerial` functions and how to do something similar in objective-c. I think I can figure out most of the math functions. I will edit the question to make it more apparent that what I really need help with are those date functions. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When working with dates in Objective-C you will often need to work with more than 1 class unlike other languages such as C#, Java and VB.NET. For creating a date from a string or getting a string from a date you will want to use the [`NSDateFormatter`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html). Now when attempting to modify or create a date with "components" (year,month,day etc.) you will want to use [`NSDateComponents`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateComponents_Class/Reference/Reference.html) along with the correct `NSCalendar`. The component solution looks like it will assist you with the DateSerial part.  The line `jdp# = inputdate + 2415018.5` should be convertible (if it is seconds) to

```
jdp = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:2415018.5 sinceDate:inputdate];
```

Comment: Excellent. Thank you for the direction. I was totally lost. I knew about `NSDate` and `NSDateFormatter`, but was unaware of `NSDateComponents`.